# 2000 Suzuki Intruder 1400 losing Prime

Tags: motorcycle, carburetor, suzuki

Bought the bike few weeks ago not running and here is where i am today. Bike will start on choke and ide all day. I get on it and give it gas it will die. Only way it will start back up is if i take rubber boot off front carb hold hand over the top it will start back i can ride but when slowing down i have to keep reving and reving or it will die and again will only refire by holding hand over top of carb. My first bike im stuck on this any advise and is it minor??

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm no bike expert, but it sounds as though the idle circuit is plugged. Might be due to ethanol gas.